# using std::move on unique_ptr on a type derived from templated base in C++1y

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++14, unique-ptr

I have problems when trying to use `std::move` semantics on templated types derived from another type. That is I get an error on the following example.

```
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class A{
};

template <typename T>
class B:A<T>{
};

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<B<int> > bar(new  B<int>());    
  std::unique_ptr<A<int> > foo (std::move(bar));
}
```

The error is on the line defining foo and it is:

```
In function 'int main()':
17:47: error: no matching function for call to 'std::unique_ptr<A<int> >::unique_ptr(std::remove_reference<std::unique_ptr<B<int> >&>::type)'
```

Obviously the non templated equivalent works fine.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/yE7Hqc).

Comment: My bad, the real problem is that I am using private inheritance, I should have written class B: public A<T>{};

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`B` privately inherits from `A`, so there is no available conversion from `B` to `A`. Change to `public` inheritance and your code will compile.

```
template <typename T>
class B: public A<T>{};
//       ^^^^^^
```

In your example, `A`'s destructor should be `virtual`, otherwise you'll have [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor#Virtual_destructors) when `foo` goes out of scope because you'll be attempting to `delete` a `B` instance via an `A *`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that I am using private inheritance.
When I change the definition of B to:
    class B: public 
Things are working.

I am keeping this other solution just for the record:
For the lack of a better idea I am resorting to this:

```
std::unique_ptr<A<int> > foo ( (A<int> * ) new  B<int>());
```

Comment: Was this the answer, or did you mean to edit your question?

Comment: This does a reinterpret cast, which likely isn't what you want.